# foreign key column doesn't want to take an insert says column can't be null

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

i'm trying to populate a foreign key column 'boss_id' from a junction table called 'clown_boss'
boss_id is new self-referencing foreign key that is meant to hold the 'id' value of the clown's boss. 
i already have a populated junction table that contains 'id' from clown_info table and newly created 'boss_id' that also references 'id' from clown.

this is what clown_info looks like:

CREATE TABLE `clown_info` (

`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

`gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,

`last_seen` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

`address` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,

`city` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,

`state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,

`appearance` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

`shirt_colour` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,

`pant_colour` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,

`hat_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,

`musical_instrument` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,

`transportation` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,

`boss_id` int NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

KEY `boss_id_sr_fk` (`boss_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `boss_id_sr_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`boss_id`) 
REFERENCES `clown_boss` (`boss_id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

i'm using the following code to try and insert values when i get the error

```
UPDATE clown_info ci
SET boss_id = (SELECT boss_id FROM clown_boss cb WHERE ci.id = cb.id) ;
```

so i just realised that boss_id is meant to reference id in the same table. it's supposed to be a lesson on self-referencing foreign keys.
so i dropped the column recreated it . recreated clown_boss put in the values and still get the same problem when trying to put values into boss_id from clown_boss table

Comment: the table i'm pulling data from is populated with data that doesn't violate the key constraints.

Comment: Please add table definitions. And often this error less than obvously thrown from a trigger

Comment: there aren't any triggers. 
table clown_boss has columns 'id' foreign key that references 'id' in the main table clown_info and column 'boss_id' which also references 'id' in clown_info
i recently added the 'boss_id' column to clown_info this is where i want to boss_id from the junction table clown_boss to go to. boss_id is meant to be a self-referencing key. there are boss_id values for every clown in the junction table 'clown_boss' 
does this help? thank you for response!

Comment: @EugeneHeynike: it would help if you could provide sample data to reproduce the problem, along with the actual definition of table `clown_info_ci`.

Comment: Please add the result for `select ci.id, cb.id from clown_info ci left outer join clown_boss cb on ci.id = cb.id`.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Please look at the formatted version of your code before posting. Use code block format, see the edit help.

Comment: it does something weird. it shows two id columns all matching 1-10 (there are 10 clowns)
but on the first column it goes up to 14 with null in second column for values 11-14
like it created 4 new clowns

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your update statement as long as a match is always found and the boss_id in clown_boss is not null then everything is fine.

Comment: An update does not insert records...

Comment: BTW are you sure you have the FK in the right place , I would normally expect a junction table to reference a master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you have set the column **'boss_id'** in table ***clown_info*** as not null.

I assume your **'boss_id'** column in table ***clown_boss*** does accept null value, right? You can't insert any null value into a 'not null' column, that is why it's showing error.

If you change your column **'boss_id'** in table ***clown_info*** to default null, your issue should be solved. Or you can modify the column **boss_id** in ***clown_boss*** to not null.

You can update your table with the following query

```
ALTER TABLE clown_info MODIFY boss_id int;
```

Column are nullable by default if you dont declare it as not null.

Comment: thank you very much! that worked.
the text i'm learning from always creates primary keys as IN NOT NULL often with AUTO_INCREMENT as well. this solution makes sense. i'll look out for it in future